# Sending POST data in the url

Tags: php, post

ok so i have a search form which submits to "search.php" i want the search.php url to include the data submited. for example: search.php?search=submited_search_form_data, my form is below to make this more clear.

```
function show_search( ) {

    $output = "<form action=\"../search.php?search=" . $submited_search_form_data . "\" method=\"post\">";
        $output .= "<div id=\"search\">";
            $output .= "<input class=\"search-box\" onfocus=\"if(this.value == ' SEARCH...'){this.value = '';}\" onblur=\"if(this.value == ''){this.value=' SEARCH...';}\" value=\" SEARCH...\" name=\"inpname\" type=\"text\">";
            $output .= "<input class=\"search-style\" type=\"submit\" name=\"search\" value=\"Search\">";
        $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</form>";

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: change `method="post"` to `method="get"`

Comment: That's called GET instead of POST.

Comment: Thanks guys i was unaware of method="get" gotta keep learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use GET, which is the method to pass data by the URL, instead of POST. And you just need to write action="../search.php" in your form markup, the browser will complete the url for you with `?inpname=...` (because search is the name of your submit button, not of your text field)